# $.get() HTML page with special character in page name

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, encodeuricomponent

I'm trying to get through `$.get()` function the content of an HTML page. This page contains in its filename the special character **+**:

```
mypage+v1.html
```

Here is how I'm trying to get the content:

```
$.get("mypage+v1.html", function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

This code works and runs fine locally, it correctly retrieves the content. As soon as I move it to a web server, it stops to work and the ajax call returns **404 Not found** error.

I tried to replace the **+** with an **_** both in the script and in the filename and it works, but I need to keep the plus sign.. I tried to use `encodeURI()`

```
$.get(encodeURI("mypage+v1.html"), function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

and also to manually replace **+** with **%2B**

```
var url = "mypage+v1.html".replace("+", "%2B");
$.get(url , function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

but it didn't do the trick..

Using

```
$.get(encodeURIComponent("mypage+v1.html"), function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

throws the following error:

```
GET http://.../mypage%2Bv1.html 404 (not found)
```

even with the encoded url it does not work.

---

Side note: I'm successfully retrieving other pages with

```
$.load("pagename.html #divToAppendTo", function(res, stat, xhr){
    ....
});
```

I need to use `$.get` because I need to manipulate and slice the file content before I append these slices in different portions of my original HTML file. I tested the `$.load()` call and it's using **Request method: GET**, this way I know that the folder is accessible..

Any other idea?

Thanks

Comment: And if you replace + by %2B?

Comment: @AdriienM thanks for the reply: I tried your suggestion, it didn't work too.. (ps: answer updated)

Comment: This sounds like a situation where you **should** never need to do what you're trying to do. Unless it's **completely** outside of your control, you should look into restricting the filenames allowed, as it's much easier to normalise those

Comment: @Joe unfortunately, it's **completely** outside of my control and I have to stick with that..

Comment: Can you retrieve the resource you want (`mypage+v1.html`) by writing its URL into the browser's address bar? Both a literal `+` and a `%2b` should work, technically, but if *manually* crafting the URL does not work you're out of luck with jQuery as well.

Comment: To confirm: mypage+v1.html is in the same location as the HTML where you are running this JQuery? E.g. `http://myserver.com/blah/jqueryget.html` is retrieving `http://myserver.com/blah/mypage+v1.html`?

Comment: Tomalak yes, it should work! @mccanff index and mypage are in 2 different directories

Comment: @BeNDerR, then you need to put a path in your URL. E.g. `/pathto/otherdir/mypage+v1.html`.

Comment: @mccanf I omitted it in the question, but I am already providing the right path to the file :(

Comment: If you use `encodeURIComponent` instead of `encodeURI` in your example above, does that change anything?

Comment: @mccannf question updated. it encodes the URL, but it does not work.. I'm starting to think the problem could be related to some server setting..

Comment: You mentioned ajax as a tag...if you use php, could you use file_get_contents() instead and return the results through ajax?

Comment: I also added JQuery as a tag :) anyway I can't test it with php right now...